# Starcraft 2 : getting gold on Psionic Assault

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I'm having a hard time reaching gold in the Psionic Assault challenge in Starcraft 2. I managed to get silver using combinations of force fields and psionic storms, but it seems that leaves me with too little energy left for the last waves. I usually end up being gg'ed right after hitting the silver mark.

I tried morphing one or two Archons after some of my templars exhausted their energy, but that only helped surviving for maybe a couple of waves. What's worse, the waves come too fast for the archons to regenerate their shields, and they're no longer capable of storming after that so I guess this is really only useful for making a last stand.

I feel I must be under-using the sentries, but every attempt I've made at using hallucinations or guardian shields only seemed to eat their energy faster without helping that much in destroying the aggressors. And without shielding they die just too fast if I send them in battle.

Am I missing something, or is it just a matter of getting a better mileage out of force fields and storms ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to get a perfect score (300) on this. Here's how:

- Use sentries as attackers. With 11 of them, your DPS is high enough, but if they start dying, you're screwed. You don't have to lose one single unit.
- If you feel like storming a big blob, try killing them with sentries first. Storm should not be used against every wave. You can skip storm completely for the first 5-10 waves or so.
- Keep sentries in 2 separate control groups in order to deal with flanks.
- Save right after and before every
  wave.
- Vary your casters. Try to minimize the number of units sitting at 200 energy. Always use the unit with the highest energy for casting.
- Templar energy is worth much more than sentry energy.
- Don't morph any Archons. You don't need a single one. Storm is much more useful.
- Guardian shield is useless.

And for some specific waves:

- When you face big numbers of reapers, wait for them to jump up the cliff, then forcefield around them and storm. They will jump down and back up, because the AI is stupid.
- Use fake Archons to tank the Ultralisk. (The Archon is generally the best hallucination.)
- Big units with energy should be feedbacked. Ghosts can be stormed, but I recommend feedback for the first wave.
- The Collosus is the hardest wave. Use one or two hallucinated Collosi for this one.
- Use fake Void Rays against the Battlecruiser.

Comment: +1 for not wasting on Guardian shield, I figure I wasted some energy there. But how do I effectively cherry pick the Sentries tat still have a lot of energy?

Comment: Use ALT to see energy (and health) of each unit. Whoever is closest will have some down. Just move those guys to the back and let smartcast pick the closest (who will then have the highest energy).

Comment: Thx for the advice. I'll try it again tonight.

Comment: Woaw. It just went like a breeze. I got trashed at 298 and stopped there, but I'll definetely try to reload and eat up the thor and mothership later on. Thx a lot to both @sapht and @jay, the advice has been incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjO_olQvHxM) helpful.

- The best way to use psi storm and force field together is to cast several forcefields in an arc (rather than a straight wall), so that enemy units will cluster in one place. This makes the storm much more effective.
- Use hallucinations (archons) to distract units which get inside your area (mainly reapers). Do so before they have a chance to spread out.
- Use high templar in pairs until they run out of energy. Once they're out, let them recharge while you use another pair. Toward the end, you might want to make a couple archons. Use them the same way as the hallucinated archons, but try to let the hallucinations take most of the damage.
- Use a single guardian shield whenever your sentries are taking fire. Your templar should hopefully never take fire.
- Don't overuse psi storm. You'll need to use the sentries to finish off enemies after they've been softened up by a storm or two.

Comment: +1 for using units in pairs to let others recharge energy

Comment: The video definitely helps. It shows a couple of micro tricks that should help avoding some of the issues I kept running into (e.g. : keeping all my templars groupped together, which made it difficult to get proper timing for the storms).